# OrientDb: Managing security/permissions based on relationships?

Tags: orientdb

The OrientDB documentation on [record level security](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-supports-the-new-record-level-security/) uses a blog as example. The user “Steve" can grant rights to individual blog posts for another user “Luke”.

However, in my situation I want Steve to be able to grant Luke access to the whole blog, so that Luke can create, edit etc all blogPosts connected to the blog as long as he has this access. And if it's revoked he shouldn't be able to edit any posts in Steve's blog even if he created them.

Can this be done somehow? I suppose record level security can't be used as it's not the same record? But maybe this behavior can be altered with a hook, or creating a user "group" for "Steve's blog" that gets the _allow rights, and both users are part of the group instead.

I'm very new to OrientDB, graphs and java, so sorry if it's a stupid question.